# Export .docx from OLE object data

Tags: xml, ms-access, openxml, docx, ole

The problem I have is, that when I read an embedded (ole) (.docx) object from "Access" database .docx. I look for the " **50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00** " hex header using c#.net. I extracted PDF, DOC, PNG, TIFF without any kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOCX files are an aggregate ([Open Packaging Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions), OPC) of XML ([WordprocessingML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)) and other formats zipped together.  (The overall DOCX / OOXML standard is described [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).)  Since zipping compresses files, it changes the binary content.  Try repeating your method on whichever OPC part you want after unzipping – the key WordprocessingML would be a good place to start: `word/document.xml`